# big JSON file in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I need help with one file "citylist.json".
This file is 29 MB and if I try to add it to my Swift project, my laptop takes 10 mins just to load the file.

Is there any solution that works with a big JSON file with Swift?
I need to use this JSON file online or remote.

I'm working with the weather API and when I need to find the city by typing the name sometimes the app crash down because what you write is not conform with the weather API.
the company what provided me the API, advice everyone need to find city by use the city code and inside on my JSON file there a list of all cities with the code.
this is the reason why i need to work with this file

Comment: Please update your question showing what you tried.

Comment: And why do you have a 29MB JSON file in your project? Sounds like you should be using a database so you never have to load so much data into memory at once.

Comment: so basically I downloaded this file provided by the company where I start to used the weather API. there is an option to find the city by name or by city code, if you have try to find city by name sometimes the app crash because the the API doesn't recogniser what you have typed and that's why they advice to download this file with inside the big JSON with all cities and city code as well, but i don't know the right way for use it.

Comment: Add additional details to the question, not here in the comments please.

Comment: Maybe better to fix that crash in the first place

Comment: I guarantee you, that I would instantly uninstall any app that tried to download a 29 MB JSON file, ***instantly***. Solve your original problem, and download only the relevant sub-section of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONSerialization is slow. There is two possible solutions.

1. Use database:

   - Add database support to your app
   - Convert JSON to database format
   - Search through database instead of JSON
2. Split one JSON into several files, based on first two (or three) letters from City name.

Let's say you have JSON with structure:

```
{
    cities: [
      ...,
      Berlin: {},
      ...,
        Monako: {},
        Moscow: {},
        ...,
    ],
}
```

You can split it to many JSON files with two letters names, example for file `mo.json`:

```
{
    cities: [
      ...,
        Monako: {},
        Moscow: {},
        ...,
    ],
}
```

That way you can speed up the process of serialization.

- You search for the appropriate file in you bundle
- You search for all city that fits your query
- For example: query `Mos` will search `mo.json` and show `Moscow`, but not `Monako`.

Comment: i wanna try first to convert the JSON to database format. thank you soo much for your help

Comment: Hi Andrei, I created the Realm database but every time I deleted my app the database is empty. what can I do?